# Equation involving fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $ K $ be a field and $f:K-\left \{ 0 \right \}\rightarrow K-\left \{ 0 \right \}$ a function with $f(f(x))=x^{-1},\forall x\in K-\left \{ 0 \right \}$ and $ f(1)\neq 1.$
Knowing that $ f^{2}(x)-f(x)+1=0 $ has an unique solution in $K-\left \{ 0 \right \} $, determine $ f(2)$.

I haven't found something useful yet.

Comment: so $f^2(x)$ is $f(x)^2$ in this context right?

Comment: Yes, it's $ f(x)^2 $.

Comment: $f$ is bijective.

Comment: I think that I proved that any field in which $x^2-x+1$ has only one root must have characteristic $2$, so $2=0$.

Comment: nevermind, the characteristic was $3$.

Comment: for an example consider $\mathbb Z_3$ and the function $f(x)=-x$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that $a$ is a root of the polynomial $x^2-x+1$.

Then $(x-a)$ divides the polynomial $x^2-x+1$.

This means that $(x-a)(x-a)=x^2-x+1$ (because the root is unique).

it follows that $x^2-2a+1=x^2-x+1$ and so $2a=1$ and $a^2=1$.

we conclude that $1=1^2=(2a)^2=4a^2=4$.

So the field must have characteristic $3$, and so $2=-1$.

Let $z=f(1)$. Notice $z^{-1}=f(f(z))=f(f(f(1))=f(1)=z$. It follows that $z^2=1$. The only two roots of the polynomial $x^2-1$ are $1$ and $-1$. We conclude $z=-1$.

So we have $f(1)=-1$, and since $1=f(f(1))=f(-1)$ we have $1=f(-1)=f(2)$.

Comment: doesn't it follow $x^2-x+1=(x-a)(x-c)$?

Comment: I think 1 = 4 means that char $K$ is $3$ not $2$.

Comment: oh yeah, good point.

Comment: How does that help finding $f(2)$?

Comment: @SSepehr thanks for the help, that did the trick!

Comment: @EugenCovaci I think the OP means a field as in mathematics, these ones are always commutative. Maybe you are thinking of the fields where horses run around and stuff?

Comment: If $ 2a=1 $ and $ a^{2}=1 $ multiplying the first relation with $ a$, we get that $ 2a^{2}=a\Leftrightarrow 2=a $, so $f(2)=0$. It's correct, isn't it?

Comment: @ztefelina I don't see how you conclude $f(2)=0$ from $2=a$. (although the other steps look good)

Comment: That's because $ a$ is a root of $f^{2}(x)-f(x)+1$.(or $f(a)$ is a root of $x^2-x+1$).

Comment: Well, something is wrong with your reasoning. I proved $f(2)=1$. And there is an example of a función that works in the comments.

Comment: Its not clear how you finish to show $f(-1)=1$.

Comment: @ReneSchipperus let $z=f(1)$, we have $f(f(z))=f(f(f(1))=f(1)=z$. We conclude $z=z^{-1}$ and so $z^2=1$. The only other element satisfying this is $-1$.

Comment: Oh, I made a mistake in my "proof"..You're right. :)

Comment: Yeah I just got that, so $f(1)=-1$ and then $f(-1)=1$.

Comment: yeah, I got a bit confused, but hopefully it's good now. Thanks for the improvements.